# Problems with code calculating up percentage

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 boxes. One is already calculating up a score, one is total amount of points possible, then 3rd box is supposed to calculate up the percentage of those 2 numbers.

I copied this from someone on jsfiddle.net to incorporate it into my HTML template but can't get it to work

```js
(function() {

  $('#pointspossible').on('input', function() {
    calculate();
  });
  $('#pointsgiven').on('input', function() {
    calculate();
  });

  function calculate() {
    var pPos = parseInt($('#pointspossible').val());
    var pEarned = parseInt($('#pointsgiven').val());
    var perc = "";
    if (isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)) {
      perc = " ";
    } else {
      perc = ((pEarned / pPos) * 100).toFixed(1);
    }

    $('#pointsperc').val(perc);
  }
});
```

```html
<DIV>
  <INPUT id=pointsgiven title="" style="MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=pointsgiven ex_ctrlid="pointsgiven" ex_ctrltype="TextField">
  <INPUT id=pointspossible title="" style="MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=pointspossible ex_ctrlid="pointspossible" ex_ctrltype="TextField">
  <DIV>
    <INPUT disabled id=pointsperc title="" style="MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=pointsperc ex_ctrlid="pointsperc" ex_ctrltype="TextField">
  </DIV>
</DIV>

<DIV></DIV>
```

The percentage isn't coming up at all. If you got 50 points out of 50 your percentage is 100%

Comment: You need to provide your html, too. Preferably a functioning demo

Comment: This is my HTML text I put the function inbetween the 2 script tags   <DIV><INPUT id=pointsgiven title="" style="MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=pointsgiven ex_ctrlid="pointsgiven" ex_ctrltype="TextField"><INPUT id=pointspossible title="" style="MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=pointspossible ex_ctrlid="pointspossible" ex_ctrltype="TextField"> 
<DIV><INPUT disabled id=pointsperc title="" style="MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=pointsperc ex_ctrlid="pointsperc" ex_ctrltype="TextField"></DIV></DIV>
<SCRIPT>


</SCRIPT>

<DIV></DIV></BODY></HTML>

Comment: You've forgotten `()` at the end of the whole `(function(){...})();`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vikashvverma/1khs8sj7/1/                                                                 This is the link to fiddle.net directly to what I copied and tried using into my own HTML.

Comment: I will try that @OPTIMUSPRIME

Comment: You forgot `$`i.e : `$(function(){`

Comment: Jquery is not included in the code above

Comment: I've been teaching myself how to use javascript with my job building HTML templates so I appreciate anyone helping me.

Comment: So did you include jQuery on the page? Are there errors, is the JavaScript in the head? Are there errors in the console? You need to debug.

Comment: been a while since I saw someone using all CAPS for html...

Comment: When I add the $ sign get a script error, $ is null or undefined, not a function object <SCRIPT>
$(function()  {           @OPTIMUSPRIME is that what it should look like at the beginning of the function?

Answer (score 1):

`$(function() {` is a document ready event handler, the $ is an alias for jQuery so it can be `jQuery(function() {` or `jQuery(document)ready(function() {` (former is preferred)

The jQuery library must be including in order to use jQuery.

Note that we can also use less code

```
 $('#pointspossible').add('#pointsgiven').on('input', function() {
    calculate();
  });
```

Or

```
$('#pointspossible,#pointsgiven').on('input', function() {
    calculate();
});
```

or even just put the function name in

```
$('#pointspossible,#pointsgiven').on('input', calculate)
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#pointspossible').on('input', function() {
    calculate();
  });
  $('#pointsgiven').on('input', function() {
    calculate();
  });

  function calculate() {
    var pPos = parseInt($('#pointspossible').val());
    var pEarned = parseInt($('#pointsgiven').val());
    var perc = "";
    if (isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)) {
      perc = " ";
    } else {
      perc = ((pEarned / pPos) * 100).toFixed(1);
    }

    $('#pointsperc').val(perc);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV>
  <INPUT id=pointsgiven title="" style="MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=pointsgiven ex_ctrlid="pointsgiven" ex_ctrltype="TextField">
  <INPUT id=pointspossible title="" style="MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=pointspossible ex_ctrlid="pointspossible" ex_ctrltype="TextField">
  <DIV>
    <INPUT disabled id=pointsperc title="" style="MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=pointsperc ex_ctrlid="pointsperc" ex_ctrltype="TextField">
  </DIV>
</DIV>

<DIV></DIV>
```